# Discord bot getting an error and not doing what it should

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

The bot looks to be functioning properly at first. I use the `?listen` command and it responds with `bot is collecting messages now...` as it should. The `?stop` command seems to do nothing and when I use the `?listen2` no matter what I put as the requested name it comes back saying `You did not specify a name on time.` The error shows up only after I use the `?listen` command. Code and Error are below. This code is my first step at figuring out how to copy all historical messages and reactions from a channel on a Discord server and pasting them to a channel on another Server.

My code is:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

require('dotenv').config();

const client = new Discord.Client();

client.login(process.env.BOT_TOKEN);

const ms = require('ms');

const prefix = '-';

const fs = require('fs');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'))
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Dahj is online!');
});

client.on('message', async message =>{
    if(message.author.bot) return;
    if(message.content.toLowerCase() === '?listen') {
        
        message.channel.send('bot is collecting messages now...');
        let filter = m => !m.author.bot;
        let collector = new discord.MessageCollector(message.channel, filter);
        let destination = client.channels.get('767508773966315550');
        collector.on('collect', (m, col) => {
            console.log("Collected message: " + m.content);
            if(destination) {
                if(m.content.toLowerCase() === '?stop' && (message.author.id === m.author.id)) {
                    console.log("Stopping collector.");
                    collector.stop();
                }
                else {
                    let embed = new discord.RichEmbed()
                        .setTitle("New Message")
                        .setDescription(m.content)
                        .setTimestamp()
                        .setAuthor(m.author.tag, m.author.displayAvatarURL)
                        .setColor('#FFAB32')
                    destination.send(embed);
                }
            }
        });
        collector.on('end', collected => {
            console.log("Messages collected: " + collected.size);
        }); 
    }
    if(message.content.toLowerCase() === '?listen2') {
        message.channel.send("Enter your name");
        let filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;
        try {
            let msg = await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { maxMatches: 1, time: '10000', errors: ['time'] });
            message.channel.send("Your name " + msg.first().content);
        }
        catch(ex) {
            message.channel.send("You did not specify a name on time.");
        }
    }
});


My error is:

(node:15556) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: discord is not defined
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\malibukid71\Documents\Dahj2\main.js:34:25)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\malibukid71\Documents\Dahj2\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\malibukid71\Documents\Dahj2\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\malibukid71\Documents\Dahj2\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\malibukid71\Documents\Dahj2\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\malibukid71\Documents\Dahj2\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\malibukid71\Documents\Dahj2\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:125:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\malibukid71\Documents\Dahj2\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:797:20)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:15556) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:15556) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit I said this as of discord.js v12 as v11 support is now over

okay first you didn't define discord you only defined 'Discord'

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
```

if you look at the error you will see what caused the error

```
ReferenceError: discord is not defined
```

and it provides the line where the issue is.so check that before

the second thing is I don't know if

```
collector.stop();
```

is a thing.sorry if I am wrong correct me.I  don't usually use collectors . but I didn't find anything like collector.stop();.

also I read the part of discord.js guide with info about collectors.
here is what I found.

i did not found anything like

```
    let collector = new discord.MessageCollector(message.channel, filter);
```

I found only

```
const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector(filter, { time: 15000 });
```

here is the link to that page : [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#message-collectors)

so maybe try using createmessagecollector.of course correct me if I am wrong